# Safari on windows doesn't work with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, safariwatir

Now that Safari is supported by default, I didn't try to compile my own Safari webdriver.

I downloaded and installed Safari 5.1.7 on my Windows 8.1.

I have the latest version of watir-webdriver and selenium-webdriver installed.

When I tried `@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:safari)`, Safari browser is launched, but I get an exception thrown.

```
irb(main):003:0> @browser = Watir::Browser.new(:safari)
Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/server.rb:37:in `read_nonblock'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/server.rb:37:in `receive'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/bridge.rb:68:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/bridge.rb:48:in `create_session'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/bridge.rb:27:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.8/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from (irb):3:in `new'
        from (irb):3
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `'
```

I can see the below in the browser.

**SafariDriver Client**

```
[  0.009s] [safaridriver.client] Requesting connection at ws://127.0.0.1:65407/wd...
[  0.026s] [safaridriver.client] Request acknowledged; connecting...
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to be the one to let you know, but I do not think you will be able to drive Safari on Windows. Well, it is not a big surprise. The current version of [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) for Mac OS is 7.0.2 and the latest supported version for Windows is 5.1.7, so it is not surprise that Selenium has trouble driving it. For more information, take a look at https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md#safari

Comment: Thanks a lot. No wi will stop tryng it on windows. Time to get a Mac. :D